# Исходный код страницы

Tags: drupal, cms

Если нажать правой кнопкой на странице сайта, то там можно найти вкладку исходный код страницы. Подскажите, пожалуйста, в какой папке сайта у drupala находится файл с этим кодом чтобы его отредактировать?

Answer (score 3):

Исходный код `Drupal` не рекомендуется изменять. Можно изменить шаблон сайта. Шаблоны находятся в директории `sites/all/themes`. Почитать о создании тем `Drupal` можно здесь: [Создание темы Drupal](http://novainfo.ru/archive/8/sozdanie-temy-drupal).

Comment: Тогда точно нужно править шаблон. Файл page.tpl.php